# Java JDBC executeBatch

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a lot of INSERT commands into my database.

```
try{
    int Records[];
    Statement title = write.getConnection().createStatement();
    Title titleFilter = application.Title.getTitle();
    ResultSet rs = titleFilter.getTitleData();

    while(rs.next()){;
        String add = ("INSERT INTO title VALUES ("
                + "'" + rs.getInt(1) + "'"+","
                + "'" +rs.getString(2)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getString(3) + "'"+","
                + "'" +rs.getInt(4)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getInt(5)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getInt(6) + "'"+","
                + "'" +rs.getString(7)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getInt(8) + "'"+","
                +"'" + rs.getInt(9)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getInt(10)+ "'" +","
                + "'" +rs.getString(11)+ "'" +","
                +"'" + rs.getString(12) + "'"+")"
        );
        title.addBatch(add);
        System.out.println(add);
        title.executeBatch();
    }
```

I know it's a little bit stupid to execute the batch right after adding an expression. I changed it to find my mistake.

Every time I try to run the program, this code part just inserts six expressions. I changed a lot of things to find my mistake, but I guess I'll never find. Furthermore I get this exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 48
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:318)....
```

Comment: Oh thx first of all.. It's just from copying it from IDE too here, is not there in my code

Comment: does any of the values containt a ``'``?

Comment: You should probably be using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) here.

Comment: use prepared statement and just set the parameters in the while loop.

Comment: Why are your integer values enclosed in quotes?  `"'" + rs.getInt(#) + "'"`

Comment: What is the point of using `addBatch` + `executeBatch` inside the loop? You might as well just call `executeUpdate`. If you want batching, move `executeBatch` outside the loop. --- And for god sake, use `PreparedStatement` and parameter markers, to prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, and failed SQL statements.

Comment: ok, going to try it with PreparedStatement. Thanks for this advise :)

Comment: Please show the code of `write.getConnection()`, and post the entire exception stacktrace, not just the fragment your posting right now.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should be using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html); this will help you to avoid syntax errors (which are hard to see when concatenating Java `String`s) among other things. Second, you are executing the batch every loop which defeats the purpose of using a batch.

Here's an example using a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO title VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement title = write.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
     ResultSet rs = titleFilter.getTitleData()) {

    while (rs.next()) {
        title.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
        title.setString(2, rs.getString(2));
        // ... do this for all the parameters ...

        title.addBatch(); // add to batch and move to next loop (if rs.next() returns true)
    }

    title.executeBatch(); // executed after loop

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // or do what you need to when an error occurs
}
```

This example also uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments by Ivan, it may be better to execute the batch after every *X* records. I'll leave the code for this as an "exercise for the reader".

Comment: Depending on number of records returned by `ResultSet` it might be better to execute batch after each X records.

Comment: I think i solve the problem with this way... Annother problem appeared but i think i'll can solve it myself..

Thanks to everyone :)